# Is there any Software to add watermark to photos in bulk?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo

Is there a software that will allow me to add my watermark to a large amount of photos in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 7):

Are you comfortable on a terminal? If so, that is **by far** your easiest option.

Take a look at the various methods associated with the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) toolchain. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533905/5374301) will be your best bet (reproduced below). The example provided would add a `watermark.jpg` on top of the image at 30% opacity.

**EDIT:** As *liori* pointed out in the comments, beware using this on anything with spaces or special characters in your filenames. It can have unexpected effects. Generally, it's safest if you only use numbers, letters, dashes, and underscores in filenames.

```
for pic in *.jpg; do
    composite -dissolve 30% -gravity south watermark.jpg $pic ${pic//.jpg}-marked.jpg
done
```

Comment: Please add relevant parts of those links to your answer with attribution.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do so. Fixed.

Comment: Be careful with filenames with spaces.